# How to automate MS Access Backend Backup?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, database-backups

I created MS Access database, and I split it to front and back-end files.
I would like backend file to be backed up on load and on close.

I could not find VBA code for such purpose. any advice?

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710003/vba-code-for-creating-access-backup